# sitemap_generator with friendly_id produces just id in URL instead of :name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sitemap

I'm using kjvarga's sitemap_generator gem and the friendly_id gem

```
gem 'sitemap_generator', '3.4'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.9"
```

If I create a sitemap using rake:sitemap:refresh I get URLs like this

www.domainname.com/images/45

But with friendly_id I use the :name attribute to define the URL like:

www.domainname.com/images/image-name

How can I make sitemap_generator produce a sitemap1.xml.gz with the correct URLs?

My sitemap.rb is

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.domainname.com/"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.add_links do |sitemap|

  Image.find_each do |image|
    sitemap.add image_path(image), :changefreq => 'monthly'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there was an error with the commit on production server that has been corrected. Now it works, so the principle layout with sitemap_generator and friendly_id is ok as described above!

Comment: thanks, I was facing the same issue. Just removing the .id attribute from the object i'm reading out makes sitemap_generator play nicely with friendly_id